# Moodle: Is it possible to get all blog entries by a teacher/admin in the form of an array etc.?

Tags: moodle

Just like we have `get_courses` function to get an array of all the courses, is there a way to retrieve a list (array, object, anything) of all the blog posts made by a user, or may be all of the blog posts on the site?

By some function? or by a database call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog posts are in this table

```
SELECT *
FROM {post}
WHERE module = 'blog'
```

There's a few fields in there for user, course etc.